How to combine multiple IF statements that use VLOOKUP and ROUND function?
I am looking to make this formula less complicated in Google Sheets.
=CONCATENATE(IF(VLOOKUP($E85,'2024 Master Data'!$C:$T,11,0)=0," ",concatenate(char(10),VLOOKUP($E85,'2024 Master Data'!$C:$T,11,0)," ",IF(ISNUMBER(VLOOKUP($E85,'2024 Master Data'!$C:$T,12,0))=TRUE, ROUND(VLOOKUP($E85,'2024 Master Data'!$C:$T,12,0),2), VLOOKUP($E85,'2024 Master Data'!$C:$T,12,0)))))


The goal is to reference another sheet called "2024 Master Data" and combine info from multiple cells into 1 cell.

The first string is wood type and the second string is amount of wood.

Only if the wood type is not blank do we want to create a new line and display the wood type followed by the amount


IF(VLOOKUP($E85,'2024 Master Data'!$C:$T,11,0)=0," ",concatenate(char(10),VLOOKUP($E85,'2024 Master Data'!$C:$T,11,0)," ",...




If the wood type is a number then we want to round it to 2 decimal places, if not we'd want to display the text.


 IF(ISNUMBER(VLOOKUP($E85,'2024 Master Data'!$C:$T,12,0))=TRUE, ROUND(VLOOKUP($E85,'2024 Master Data'!$C:$T,12,0),2), VLOOKUP($E85,'2024 Master Data'!$C:$T,12,0))



Is there any way to make this less complicated? This formula only pulls 1 wood type and amount of wood. There could be up to 7 types of wood needed so this formula would be 7x.
Ex: A final cell that has 3 wood types would show:
4/4 beech 1.5
6/4 walnut 3.5
8/4 walnut 2.8

Please [edit] your question to include a sample of your source data and also an example of your desired result in markdown format.

share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

If you shared a sample of your actual data it is possible the formula could be simplified further.

Single ROW Formula
=LET(rng,'2024 Master Data'!C:T, r,MATCH(E85,INDEX(rng,,1),0),
   a,INDEX(rng,r,11), b,INDEX(rng,r,12),
   IF(a=0,,char(10)&a&" "&IF(ISNUMBER(b), ROUND(b,2), b)))

Multi-Row Formula
Assumes your lookup values are in E85:E100
=LET(types,E85:E100, rng,'2024 Master Data'!C:T, 
   MAP(types, LAMBDA(t, IFNA(LET(
     r,MATCH(t,INDEX(rng,,1),0),
     a,INDEX(rng,r,11), b,INDEX(rng,r,12),
     IF(a=0,,char(10)&a&" "&IF(ISNUMBER(b), ROUND(b,2), b)))))))

Functions Used
BYCOL  FILTER  IF  IFNA  INDEX  ISNUMBER  LAMBDA  LET  MAP  MATCH  ROUND
Saving Space
Character Counts
Character counts are based on formulas after any unnecessary spaces and line breaks have been removed.

297 - Your original formula
150 - Single row formula above
236 - Multi row formula above

Savings

-23 charsThe second CONCATENATE function nested in the formula is redundant and the other CONCATENATE is used to join four strings and can be eliminated by joining them with & operators instead.
=IF(VLOOKUP($E85,'2024 Master Data'!$C:$T,11,0)=0," ",
  char(10)&VLOOKUP($E85,'2024 Master Data'!$C:$T,11,0)&" "&
  IF(ISNUMBER(VLOOKUP($E85,'2024 Master Data'!$C:$T,12,0))=TRUE,
    ROUND(VLOOKUP($E85,'2024 Master Data'!$C:$T,12,0),2),
    VLOOKUP($E85,'2024 Master Data'!$C:$T,12,0)))


-71 chars
Using LET and storing the lookup range 2024 Master Data'!$C:$T in a named variable rng reduces code duplication as it is referenced 5 times.
=LET(rng,'2024 Master Data'!$C:$T, 
   IF(VLOOKUP($E85,rng,11,0)=0," ",char(10)&VLOOKUP($E85,rng,11,0)&" "&
     IF(ISNUMBER(VLOOKUP($E85,rng,12,0))=TRUE,
       ROUND(VLOOKUP($E85,rng,12,0),2),VLOOKUP($E85,rng,12,0))))


-38 chars The five near-duplicate VLOOKUP's (2 have column index 11, and 3 have 12) can be replaced by single MATCH formula r to calculate the correct row, and then column 11 and column 12 of r can be stored in a and b for reuse.
 =LET(rng,'2024 Master Data'!$C:$T,r,MATCH($E85,INDEX(rng,,1),0),
    a,INDEX(rng,r,11),b,INDEX(rng,r,12),
    IF(a=0," ",char(10)&a&" "&IF(ISNUMBER(b)=TRUE,ROUND(b,2),b)))


-12 chars
From =TRUE, " ", and $
=LET(rng,'2024 Master Data'!C:T,r,MATCH(E85,INDEX(rng,,1),0),
   a,INDEX(rng,r,11),b,INDEX(rng,r,12),
   IF(a=0,,char(10)&a&" "&IF(ISNUMBER(b),ROUND(b,2),b)))


Where an IF function's condition can only return TRUE or FALSE, there is no need to test for truthiness:  ✅  IF(true,1,0)
❌  IF(true=true,1,0)
✅  IF(ISNUMBER(x),1,0)
❌  IF(ISNUMBER(x)=true,1,0) 

IF functions should return empty values, not empty text strings "" or spaces " " (unless there is a specific need). It saves  characters but it is also good practice as it avoids problems with other functions: ✅  IF(false, 1, )
❌  IF(false, 1, "")
❌  IF(false, 1, " ")

There is no indication that the columns need to be absolute so $ removed unless needed.



